# Как запретить выделение содержимого на вебстранице?

Tags: html, javascript, css

Как кросбразерно запретить выделение элементов на вебстранице в определённом блоке?

Comment: дык, так этот трюк защитит только от детей, кто захочет тот выделит то что надо и скопирует, или это не про защиту текста?

Comment: Да нет я просто делаю окна которые перетаскиваются мышкой и выделение мешает!

Comment: От блондинок можно, от бытых юзеров нет! Методов масса как обойти блокировки... Так что проще не морочить себе голову) ИМХО!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это останавливает выделение! 
У меня в Drag&Drop работает так.

```
elem.onselectstart = function() {
    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 12):

```
*[unselectable=on] {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select:none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
     user-select: none;
}

 для IE

unselectable="on"
```

Comment: Это не запрещает выделение.

Comment: @exec а что же это делает?

Answer (score 11):

```
.no-select {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Или:

```
.no-select {
    user-select: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Тут полный ответ - 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4407335/7580988

> According to Can I use, the user-select is currently supported in all browsers except Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions (but sadly still needs a vendor prefix).

All of the correct CSS variations are:

```
.noselect {
-webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
-webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
 -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
   -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
        user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                              supported by Chrome and Opera */
}

<p>
Selectable text.
</p>
<p class="noselect">
Unselectable text.
</p>
```

http://www.bootply.com/m6kEm8DNIq

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы value в Input нельзя было выделить? из статьи на Хабре просто сразу говориться (кроме элементов INPUT и TEXTAREA)

Answer (score 0):

Поставьте div в position: absolute; и слоем выше всех остальных элементов. [Смотрите пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/3QQsN/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="cover"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#cover {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Выделил спокойно.

Comment: Аха..))) И почему у меня ощущение, что знакомые вас не долюбливают за занудство? ))) В самом первом коментарии, makregistr дал исчерпывающий ответ. Просто люди предлагали возможные варианты, а не ломали головы, как на все сто процентов решить проблему.

Comment: Я пришол к выводу что надо всё три ответа засунить на вебстраницу одновременно и всё будет ОК:)

Comment: спасибо 011010101010011 за проверку вариантов!

Comment: @Rules, на Ваш вопрос есть ответ, просто нужно искать. Пихать что попало не нужно, читаем - [http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/webdev/18080/][1]


  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/webdev/18080/

Answer (score 0):

Человек уже давал ссылку на хабр. Их решение работает! Вот оно:

```
function preventSelection(element){
  var preventSelection = false;

  function addHandler(element, event, handler){
    if (element.attachEvent) 
      element.attachEvent('on' + event, handler);
    else 
      if (element.addEventListener) 
        element.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
  }
  function removeSelection(){
    if (window.getSelection) { window.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); }
    else if (document.selection && document.selection.clear)
      document.selection.clear();
  }
  function killCtrlA(event){
    var event = event || window.event;
    var sender = event.target || event.srcElement;

    if (sender.tagName.match(/INPUT|TEXTAREA/i))
      return;

    var key = event.keyCode || event.which;
    if (event.ctrlKey && key == 'A'.charCodeAt(0))  // 'A'.charCodeAt(0) можно заменить на 65
    {
      removeSelection();

      if (event.preventDefault) 
        event.preventDefault();
      else
        event.returnValue = false;
    }
  }

  // не даем выделять текст мышкой
  addHandler(element, 'mousemove', function(){
    if(preventSelection)
      removeSelection();
  });
  addHandler(element, 'mousedown', function(event){
    var event = event || window.event;
    var sender = event.target || event.srcElement;
    preventSelection = !sender.tagName.match(/INPUT|TEXTAREA/i);
  });

  // борем dblclick
  // если вешать функцию не на событие dblclick, можно избежать
  // временное выделение текста в некоторых браузерах
  addHandler(element, 'mouseup', function(){
    if (preventSelection)
      removeSelection();
    preventSelection = false;
  });

  // борем ctrl+A
  // скорей всего это и не надо, к тому же есть подозрение
  // что в случае все же такой необходимости функцию нужно 
  // вешать один раз и на document, а не на элемент
  addHandler(element, 'keydown', killCtrlA);
  addHandler(element, 'keyup', killCtrlA);
}
```